# Animate element moving columns in a Grid?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

```
Grid.SetColumn(Image, 0);
```

Using a Grid with 1 row and 3 distinct columns, the command above can be used to move an element, in this case an Image, from one column to the next. In example, moving from columns 0-1, 1-0, 1-2, and 2-1. The command works great but the image 'teleporting' from one column to the next is rather static.

In an effort to polish the movement, the code below can be used to animate the image movement:

```
await Image.TranslateTo(-100, 0, 1000); // Move image left
```

However, this requires fiddling with the exact distance to travel from one column to another. Unsure if using a static number will translate to the same visual change on devices of varying size, thus here I am.

Is there a way to animate an element moving between columns, utilizing Grid.SetColumn for precise movement? Or, is there a way to calculate the change in X Grid.SetColumn is making and using that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `ActualWidth` is internal in Xamarin: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/ColumnDefinition.cs, we can't use it to get each column's width at run time. It may be not perfect, but we can also get the width by adding a `StackLayout` in each column's root position. Then we can get the width through using the `StackLayout`'s width.

Suppose the image you want to translate is in Column 0. Here is my way to move between columns:

```
//get each column's width by stackLayout
var firstWidth = FirstStack.Width;
var secondWidth = SecondStack.Width;
var thirdWidth = ThirdStack.Width;

//put the distances we need to translate in a list, notice to add the ColumnSpacing.
List<double> distanceList = new List<double>();
distanceList.Add(0);
distanceList.Add(firstWidth + MyGrid.ColumnSpacing);
distanceList.Add(firstWidth + secondWidth + MyGrid.ColumnSpacing * 2);
```

Then when you want to move from (any column) - 0, use

```
await Image.TranslateTo(distanceList[0], 0);
//any - 1
await Image.TranslateTo(distanceList[1], 0);
...
```

This is for items in Column 0, for 1 or 2 you need to modify the `distanceList`. It may be a little complicated, but can meet your requirement.

Comment: Thanks Land! As it turns out, we can use Image.Width and circumvent adding StackLayouts to obtain width. See: `await ImageName.TranslateTo(0, 0); // left
await ImageName.TranslateTo(ImageName.Width, 0); // center
await ImageName.TranslateTo(ImageName.Width*2, 0); // right` The formatting in this comment is poor, but hopefully this conveys my implementation based off your solution